# Facebook API not returning friends birthday using friends_birthday permission

Tags: facebook

```
$fb_friends = $f1->getFacebookFriends();
$fb_friends_Count = $f1->displayFriendCount(array('users'=>$fb_friends, 'nb_display'=>1));

//get current date
$date_now=getdate();
$current_day=$date_now['mday'];
$current_month=$date_now['mon'];
$current_year=$date_now['year'];

//get friends' details  
for($u=0; $u<$fb_friends_Count; $u++) {
    $fb_friends_id=$fb_friends[$u]['id'];
    $friend_profile1="http://graph.facebook.com/".$fb_friends_id."/";
    $friend_profile = @file_get_contents($friend_profile1);
    $friend_profile = json_decode($friend_profile,true);    
    $gender=$friend_profile['gender'];
    print_r($friend_profile);

    //get birthday
    $birthday=$friend_profile['birthday'];
```

Here is my code. I already have the user_birthday, friends_birthday permission but the `print_r($friend_profile);` only shows this: `Array ( [id] => xxxxxxx [name] => Joye Tanay Lipata [first_name] => Joye [middle_name] => Tanay [last_name] => Lipata [link] => http://www.facebook.com/joye.lipata [username] => joye.lipata [gender] => female [locale] => en_US )`

The birthday is not showing.

Comment: Is this for _all_ friends you’re querying, or just for specific once? If a user has set their privacy settings so that their birthday will not get shared with apps their friends are using, then you will _not_ get a birthday value for such a friend.

Comment: this is for all of my friends.. I don't know why but the birthday doesn't show in the array

Comment: They are probably hiding their birthday information.

Answer (score 2):

You must use current access_token parameter in graph api call

```
$friend_profile1 = "http://graph.facebook.com/".$fb_friends_id."/?access_token=".$access_token;
```

Comment: i already have that in my function:  function getFacebookFriends($criteria='') {
  $name = $criteria['name'];
  
  if($name=='') $name = 'me';
  
  $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$name.'/friends?access_token='.$this->getAccessToken();
  $content = @file_get_contents($url,0,null,null);
  $content = json_decode($content,true);
  
  $users = $this->formatFacebookUsers($content);
  
  return $users;
 }

Comment: It is just used getting user friends. In your for loop, you are making another graph api request which has no access_token parameter. Use access_token parameter all graph api calls..

Comment: i used that for getting the gender of my friends..and the gender is showing properly.. but why is the birthday not showing? i dont know if it is permission issue.. but i have set user_birthday and friends_birthday in my app and in the scope...

Comment: "graph.facebook.com/$fb_friends_id" and "graph.facebook.com/$fb_friends_id/?access_token=$access_token" gives you different results. Without access_token, you only get user public data (like gender) but with access_token parameter you get all information you can with permissions. So, before for loop, get access token and assign a variable, then in for loop, add access_token parameter after graph api url (ie. graph.facebook.com/$userId/?access_token=$access_token )..

Comment: i have this in my getFacebookFriends function $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' .$name.' /friends?access_token='.$this->getAccessToken(); it will not work?

Comment: It works only that api call. Use access_token parameter **ALL** your Graph Api calls.